# bad result of my code

Tags: java, debugging

I seem to have a problem, where the output I expect is:

```
9000 + 200 + 50 + 6
```

But I get:

```
90000 + 2000 + 500 + 60
```

Here is my code:

```
class Kata
{
    public static String expandedForm(int num) {
        String s =  String.valueOf(num);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(s.charAt(i) == '0') continue;
            result.append(s.charAt(i) + makesZero(s.length() - i));
            if(i != s.length() - 1) result.append(" + ");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static String makesZero(int num) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            result.append("0");
        return result.toString();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Kata.expandedForm(9256));
    }
}
```

Comment: debugging or drawing (and following) flowchart can fix those! this is typical +1/-1 problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with a classic off-by-one error. This is easily solved, but the larger problem with your approach is that you are solving the problem in an unnatural way, which makes your code more difficult to understand and debug. Determining how many zeroes to add is fundamentally a math problem but you are treating it like a string problem, which reduces the expressiveness of your code.

Here is a suggested rewrite of your `expandedForm` method that approaches this problem in a different way.

```
public static String expandedForm(int num) {
    if (num == 0)
        return "0";

    int zeroes = (int) Math.log10(num);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    while (zeroes >= 0) {
        int multiple = (int) Math.pow(10, zeroes);
        int digit = num / multiple;
        result.append(String.valueOf(digit * multiple));

        if (zeroes > 0)
            result.append(" + ");

        num = num % multiple;
        --zeroes;
    }

    return new String(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At

```
result.append(s.charAt(i) + makesZero(s.length() - i));
```

line you are appending character at position `i` and `length - i` zeroes. Lets see what happens for `s="9256"`.

If `i=0`

- `s.charAt(i)`->`s.charAt(0)`->`'9'` (that looks OK)
- `makesZero(s.length() - i)` -> `makesZero(4 - 0))` -> `makesZero(4)` -> `"0000"`.

So as you see you are adding one extra zero because you didn't take into account that while `9` represents thousands, but thousands despite having 4 digits should have 3 zeroes. So you need to reduce one zero with

**`makesZero(s.length() - i - 1)`.**

---

BTW `builder.append(foo + bar)` (when `+` represents concatenation, not addition) should be written as `builder.append(foo).append(bar)`. Otherwise you are ending with something like

`builder.append(new StringBuilder().append(foo).append(bar).toString())`

which means you still need to create separate builder for each `+`.

We are using `StringBuilder#append` precisely so we could avoid `+` and such unnecessary object creation.

Answer (score -2):

Just start your loop with i = 1 and i <= s. length()

Comment: the same problem is, you can compile, i use intellij idea

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone. But this definetely should solve the problem